# Asking for pairs of information on a x_mdialog for scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm creating a program to calculate the linear regression of data. The program should, when you start, ask for the number of pairs of values (x and y) to be used. And according to the number of pairs that you define, it should go asking for the data to apply the regression (on pairs of X, Y). The program must apply regression for all methods available.

I already have the code for the regressions but the problem that I have is that I don't know how to ask for the data (the pairs of x and y) and for x create a vector, and for y create a separate vector. Also, it can be from 3 pairs to infinite number of pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want. One possible way is to use a for-loop:

1. Inquiry the users on how many points they want to input, `n_pairs`, as you said.
2. Use a for-loop from 1 to `n_pairs` asking for inputs using `x_mdialog`.
3. At each iteration, evaluate the input and store the data.

Something like the following could work for you:

```
//inquiry how many pairs
n_pairs = x_mdialog("Data acquisition","How many points will you enter?","3");
n_pairs = evstr(n_pairs);

//initialise data
X_data = []; Y_data = [];

for i = 1 : n_pairs
    //acquire each pair
    pair = x_mdialog("Data acquisition",["X:","Y:"],["",""])

    if pair(1) == "" | pair(2) == "" | pair == [] then
        //break loop in case of blank input
        break
    else
        //non-blank inputs are stored
        X_data(i) = evstr(pair(1));
        Y_data(i) = evstr(pair(2));
    end
end

//sort values accordint to X
[X_data,idx] = gsort(X_data,"r","i");
Y_data = Y_data(idx);
```